# Azure DevOps build support for referencing separate project directly instead of via Nuget via Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a project *A* that references project *B* in Visual Studio, which works locally. The folder structure of both is below:

```
C:\code\A
C:\code\B
```

But on Azure DevOps Repos, each project resides in a separate repo of a separate project, like below:

```
repo A in Project A
repo B in Project B
```

The project is the build pipeline throws exception when building project *A* that cannot find project *B*.

Is there a solution instead of using Nuget?

The downside of using nuget is that when in debug mode, we cannot step into the assembly.

Comment: What are you using for source control? Git, or TFVC? Also, for what it's worth, you **can** debug a NuGet package if you include the symbols.

Comment: It is Azure DevOps Git. Hwo to include the symbols?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure DevOps build support for referencing separate project directly instead of via Nuget via Visual Studio

There should be some way to do this, but the best solution is to have a single repository.

To resolve this issue, you can:

- Add the `.dll` file of dependent project to a the NuGet package.
  upload to a feed, such as Azure Devops feed: Package Management in Azure Devops and
  TFS, then restore packages during the build (This is the way we are
  using).

  For the **debugging**, you could publish the symbols package to the artifact by the task  [Publish symbols path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops). Check [this blog](https://www.liftrtech.net/home/blog?name=ASP.NET-Core-Debugging-Nuget-Packages-with-AzureDevOps-VSTS-Symbol-Server) for the details.
- Add [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to build definition to
  download the artifact of project B build. You also can call [Builds
  REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-build-artifacts) through PowerShell to get build artifacts of project B.
- You can consider to use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [Git Subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) if it is Git
  repository.
- If you are using TFVC repository, you can get the Extensions project
  by specify additional Workspace mappings in Get Sources section of
  build definition (Specify it directly, can click … to select)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You listed a few ways. which way should I use, we are using Azure DevOps Git, ?

Comment: @Pingpong, You can use the first three ways. Personally, I recommend you to use the first method. This is the method we are using. It has more advantages in publishing and sharing.

Comment: just to double check, you solution are for using Nuget, or not using Nuget?

Comment: @Pingpong, using nuget.